# Ember: Re-render a route's template when the model changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've noticed that a route doesn't re-render when the model changes (i.e. `transitionTo` the same route with a different model). I have some jQuery plugins set up on a particular page and I need them to re-render when the model changes, so it appears as a fresh page.

Is there a way to do this? Perhaps by observing the model's ID and firing a re-render of the route somehow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that you want your route to re-render when the model changes? So you want to do something like model.save(), and then you want the page to reload in order to re-run your jQuery plugins? Is there a hook into your jQuery plugin? Could you do something like `model.save().then(() => /* jQueryPlugin.refresh() /* })` ?

Comment: I just need the template to rerender when the route is entered, regardless of the previous route. The current Ember functionality is that if you transitionTo the same route with a different model, only the data bindings are updated - the view isn't re-rendered.

Comment: Aaaah, sorry, my mistake. I thought you were saying that the data-bindings _weren't_ updating for some reason. I understand now. You want not only the data bindings to update, but the entire template to re-render.

Answer (score 2):

I have an [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3d68118c6787a60516c5dc6b67fd2ea5?openFiles=components.tick-tock.js%2Ctemplates.components.tick-tock.hbs&route=%2Fshow%2F1) that, I believe, does what you're looking for, but first I would like to argue there are no straightforward ways to do what you're asking because it is **the opposite of what an SPA is designed to do**.

Data binding (without refreshing the view) is typically a boon of an SPA, and the SPA works hard to *avoid* brute force reloading/refreshing/rerendering the view at all costs. It took me a while to find *a* solution to your question as it is stated because it seems to go against Ember design principles. Even hooks like [`route refresh()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Route/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh&show=inherited%2Cprotected%2Cprivate%2Cdeprecated) are meant to update the model and bound data, not reload the template.

[Although](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771291/route-refresh-in-ember-does-not-clear-input-controls-content) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481255/how-to-reload-current-route-in-ember-js) [people](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-re-render-component/11081) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145070/refresh-reload-ember-route-from-a-component) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927159/force-to-refresh-ember-view) the same question before, it seems that most answers guide users towards **not** refreshing the whole view. More often than not, the ideal of refreshing the view is an incorrect assumption.

Following previous examples, I would suggest that **your goal shouldn't be to refresh the template completely, but rather, figure out how you can make your jQuery plugin better fit in to a Single Page App/client-side JS friendly design** and have it reload as a natural part of the route lifecycle.

For instance, maybe the plugin can be reloaded/reset/re-run in [`afterModel()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Route/methods/refresh?anchor=afterModel&show=inherited%2Cprotected%2Cprivate%2Cdeprecated) or somewhere similar.

That said, I was able to accomplish what you asked for using (**in my opinion, a hack**) `Ember.run.later()` so that I could invalidate an `if` block and force the content to rerender. Note, this is typically *not* what users want since (aside from design principle reasons) it causes UI flicker.

I have a component like so.

```
/* will-rerender.hbs */
{{#if show}}
    {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

And it has a JS file like so.

```
/* will-rerender.js */
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  show: false,

  didReceiveAttrs() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    /* 
      Ugly hack, but we need to reset `show` in
      a separate run loop in order to force the view
      to rerender.
    */

    this.set('show', false);

    Ember.run.later(() => {
      this.set('show', true);
    });
  }
});
```

You can invoke it like this...

```
/* your template */
{{#will-rerender cacheKey=model.id}}
   ... your content to rerender ...
{{/will-rerender}}
```

Whenever the `model.id` changes the component will invoke `didReceiveAttrs()` causing `show` to invalidate and the view to refresh.

As an aside, I think the behavior of switching between models would be much more natural with `{{link-to}}` rather than calling `transitionTo` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this example, Will. I think my situation can be better described by saying that the reason the components need to re-render is that they in fact load data. Some of them are charts (Chart.js) that fetch the data themselves, rather an given data from the route. I think your solution will still work but I'm wondering if that additional insight could lead to a more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks for the additional context, Adam. If the end goal is to reload data for the charts, what about using the [Chart.js APIs for updating data](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)? You could potentially bind an action in your component or controller to update the Chart.js data array.

Comment: Will, I did have success using the update data API, in combination with `ember-diff-attrs` and computed functions observing the model ID.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you got it going Adam.